# Laravel Prequel configured successfully, but getting port error when opened

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a new database with the Laravel framework.
The DB name is Prequel. I have configured it so that's done, but I am facing some problem. It's related to the port number because MySql DB and Prequel database's port number is the same.

I have stopped Mysql DB so port 3306 is free, but Prequel is not working.

[Screenshot of the error page I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhnPm.png)

Comment: It seems like your definition of the port number is wrong as it sais you have a irregular port setup: NaN(Not a number)

Comment: Please Give Solution How can Solve it

Comment: I will try to solve this problem but not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix the grammar a bit so that it is more understandable. I've also removed the Prequel tag, because it refers to a Scala library and not the Prequel tool you're talking about in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prequel](https://github.com/Protoqol/Prequel) isn't a database itself. It's a tool to manage databases. You still need to run MySQL and your database configuration values need to be the same as before (before you installed Prequel).

The database configuration values you see in the Prequel [config](https://github.com/Protoqol/Prequel/blob/master/config/prequel.php#L37) is meant to tell Prequel where your (existing) database is.

Comment: Hi @programsmagic if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.